# Adding notifications using datepicker

Tags: ios, datepicker, calendar, apple-push-notifications, xcode8

import UIKit
import UserNotifications

class CreateTaskViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var importantSwitch: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var taskNameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!


    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerselectedDate(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
}
@IBAction func datePickerselectedDate(_ sender: Any) {



}
@IBAction func addTapped(_ sender: Any) {


    // Create Task from the outlet info

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    let task = Task(context: context)

    task.name = taskNameTextField.text!
    task.important = importantSwitch.isOn
    (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()

    navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)


}




    func scheduleNotification(at date: Date) {

        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

        let task = Task(context: context)

        task.name = taskNameTextField.text!
        task.important = importantSwitch.isOn
        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()


        let calander = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        let components = calander.dateComponents(in: .current, from: date)
        let newComponents = DateComponents(calendar: calander, timeZone: .current,  month: components.month, day: components.day, hour: components.hour, minute: components.minute)

        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: newComponents, repeats: false)
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Reminder!!"
        content.body = task.name!
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "textNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {(error) in if let error = error {
            print("Uh oh! we had an error:\(error)")

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge ], completionHandler: {didAllow, error in })




            }

    }


}

}
```

I did not use the datePickerselected func as I did not know what you mean by adding the date to my action. This is what i have now it still does not notify the user after i set a date. I want to be able to set a date to be notified as a notification.

Comment: did you try the below code

Comment: I did but the pop view did not work and what should I do with my date picker action I was able to call the func scheduleNotification outside but still was not getting it right.

Comment: And thanks for the response I am fairly new to Xcode I just recently started on my own and want to learn more.

Comment: Can you update the code with modified code

Comment: I saw you updated the code in my answer as an edit which wasn't making any sense. Update the code always in your own Question as an update. I can then compare on what you did :)

Comment: Will do just getting the hang of asking questions on here haha

Comment: updated the code

Comment: Code looks fine. What is the issue you are getting. I have just updated my answer below with UPDATE 1 which is just a method change and your date picker should work. I am assuming your IBACtion method datePickerselectedDate is called when date is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created your scheduleNotification function inside the addTapped action hence you are not able to call it from anywhere else. Create it outside.

```
@IBAction func addTapped(_ sender: Any) {


// Create Task from the outlet info

let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

let task = Task(context: context)

task.name = taskNameTextField.text!
task.important = importantSwitch.isOn
(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()

}

func scheduleNotification(at date: Date) {

    let calander = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    let components = calander.dateComponents(in: .current, from: date)
    let newComponents = DateComponents(calendar: calander, timeZone: .current,  month: components.month, day: components.day, hour: components.hour, minute: components.minute)

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: newComponents, repeats: false)
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Reminder!!"
    content.body = task.name!
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "textNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {(error) in if let error = error {
        print("Uh oh! we had an error:\(error)")

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge ], completionHandler: {didAllow, error in })
        }
```

Then you can call it outside and pass the date from your Date picker action.

In your view did load  add the below line -

```
datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerselectedDate(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
```

And assuming you want your selector method to be **datePickerselectedDate** the one you have created, modify it as below

```
func datePickerselectedDate(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {

    scheduleNotification(date : sender.date)
}
```

**UPDATE 1**
After your updated change, just change the below method -

```
@IBAction func datePickerselectedDate(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {

       scheduleNotification(date : sender.date)

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much It works great now! althought i set it as scheduleNotification( at: sender.date)

Comment: Great. Glad I could help. Please accept the answer. :)